# Mocha Chai Sequelize: I can't make tests fail

Tags: mocha.js, sequelize.js, chai

I am trying to write test for a model in sequelize, but I do not understand why it is not failing

```
it('should find user by id', (done) => {
  users.findByPk(2)
  .then((retrievedUser) => {
    expect(retrievedUser.dataValues).to.deep.equal('it should break');
    done();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`something went wrong [should find user by id] ${err}`);
    done();
  })
});
```

When I run the test the output is the following

```
something went wrong [should find user by id] AssertionError: expected { Object (id, email, ...) } to deeply equal 'it should break'
1   -__,------,
0   -__|  /\_/\
0   -_~|_( ^ .^)
    -_ ""  ""

  1 passing (40ms)
```

If someone want to watch the full code, I created a [project](https://github.com/agusgambina/dreamy-hawking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an asynchronous Mocha test to fail, pass an error as an argument to the done callback function

```
it('should find user by id', (done) => {
  users.findByPk(2)
  .then((retrievedUser) => {
    expect(retrievedUser.dataValues).to.deep.equal('it should break');
    done();
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(`something went wrong [should find user by id] ${err}`);
    done(err);
  })
});
```

Alternatively, use an async function without a callback:

```
it('should find user by id', async () => {
  const retrievedUser = await users.findByPk(2);
  try {
    expect(retrievedUser.dataValues).to.deep.equal('it should break');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`something went wrong [should find user by id] ${err}`);
    throw err;
  }
});
```

That said, I wouldn't recommend logging the error message of failing tests, because that's what Mocha already does for you in a typical setup. So I would get rid of the try-catch block in the example above.

```
it('should find user by id', async () => {
  const retrievedUser = await users.findByPk(2);
  expect(retrievedUser.dataValues).to.deep.equal('it should break');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the feedback, it worked passing the err. I understood and delete the "console.log" line in the error. On the other hand, I prefer to test in an asynchronous way.